# jQuery get div prev in change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html code like :

```
<div class="callcenter" style="" data-id="2">
  <select class="entityChange">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="8">callcenter1</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And an event like :

```
        $(document).on('change', '.entityChange', function() {
            var ficheId = $(this).prev().attr("data-id");
            var type = $(this).prev().attr("data-type");
            var newUserId = $(this).val();

            console.log($(this).prev());
        });
```

I'm trying to retrieve attribut of my first div in this event but i can't with prev().

Any ideas ?

Comment: Tip: Instead of doing this `.attr("data-id")`, do it like this `.data("id")`.

Comment: By the way, there is no `data-type` attribute on `<div>`

Comment: `.prev()` and `.next()` jQuery API methods don't relate to an element `parent` or `child`. They relate to an element `sibling` (same level in the DOM tree).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `.parent()` since it is a parent and not a sibling, with which you can use `prev`

```
    $(document).on('change', '.entityChange', function() {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var ficheId = parent.attr("data-id");
        var type = parent.attr("data-type");
        var newUserId = $(this).val();
        console.log(parent);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

`div` is a parent, so you can use `.closest()`

Use

```
var ficheId = $(this).closest('.callcenter').attr("data-id");
```

or

You can use `.parent()`

```
var ficheId = $(this).parent().attr("data-id");
```

I would recomment you to use `.data()` instead of `.attr()` like

```
var ficheId = $(this).parent().data("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> $('.entityChange').change(function() {
>
> ```
> var ficheId = $(this).parent().data('id');
> ```
>
> });

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code, It is working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.entityChange').on('change',function() {
            var ficheId = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
            var type = $(this).parent().attr("data-type");
            var newUserId = $(this).val();
            console.log($(this).parent());
        });

});
```

Output will be

```
Object[div.callcenter]
```

**Link :**  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e2h4bnp4/1/)